# need to create new array called result with key/value from posts and inside that reviews array with user and comment key/value objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

For the below input data:

```
    let posts = [
        {
            "id": 101,
            "title": "Some post title"
        },
        {
            "id": 102,
            "title": "Some Another post title"
        },
        {
            "id": 103,
            "title": "Some Best post title ever"
        }
    ]

    let reviews = [
        {
            "postId": 101,
            "user": "Chris",
            "comment": "Great post!"
        },
        {
            "postId": 101,
            "user": "Jason",
            "comment": "Worth reading."
        },
        {
            "postId": 102,
            "user": "Dave",
            "comment": "Waste of time"
        }
    ]
```

I would like to return this result data:

```
    let result = [{ id: 101, title: "Some post title", reviews: [{ user: "John", Comment: "Great post!" }] }]
```

could only get values but need reviews array without id and should be inside new result with post id and title

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: do you have any solution you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` with `filter`:

```js
let posts = [{
    "id": 101,
    "title": "Some post title"
  },
  {
    "id": 102,
    "title": "Some Another post title"
  },
  {
    "id": 103,
    "title": "Some Best post title ever"
  }
]

let reviews = [{
    "postId": 101,
    "user": "Chris",
    "comment": "Great post!"
  },
  {
    "postId": 101,
    "user": "Jason",
    "comment": "Worth reading."
  },
  {
    "postId": 102,
    "user": "Dave",
    "comment": "Waste of time"
  }
]

const res = posts.map(({
  id,
  title
}) => ({
  id,
  title,
  reviews: reviews.filter(({
    postId
  }) => postId == id).map(({
    user,
    comment
  }) => ({
    user,
    comment
  }))
}));

console.log(res);
```